# does my application requires a google maps license if it only uses google maps links

Tags: google-maps

I have a question whether my application requires a google maps license or not.
I developed an app soon to be published on android and ios app stores, my app will be free of charge, does not require any subscriptions from the user, no login, and will be accessible to everyone for free. The application will contain ads. The purpose of the application is to guide the user to navigate using the street addressing system by entering a street number and building number, so it will open a google link for example : "https://www.google.com/maps/dir//33.8421723,35.575907/@33.8421723,35.575907,18z"
This link will be opened in a browser or in the google maps application.

My income will be from municipalities who want their addressing system to be included in the application, so the municipalities will pay for me to put the links on my server to be opened by the free application. In this case, am i required to purchase a license from google?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal issues (terms of use), not coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question you're not using any Google Maps API, you're just linking to google maps website.. and they will serve the information..

I would say linking to Google Maps is not using there maps in your app so I believe it's free of charges